# code coverage analysis without unit tests by using dotcover

Tags: code-coverage, dotcover

We have to do code coverage analysis for dotnet application with out unit testing.For this, business has recommended to explore "dotcover" tool. As we are new to the tool and we are not sure how we can do code coverage with out unit tests by using dotcover.

Can anyone help me by providing any references or steps to do code coverage analysis without unit tests ?